# Insert dynamic DATE metadata with PHP

Tags: php

I am importing content using cron with a PHP script and has a field called _expiration_date that I need to dynamically populate 20 days in advance based on the current date of import.  If I create the record manually using the PHP program and look at the record, the program creates the data in the _expiration_date field in this format: 1449203160  which translates out to human form as Dec 4, 2015 @ 4:26.

I assume this is some sort of date/timestamp?

As you can see below the fields I am populating are static text.  How do I populate the _expiration_date field dynamically in the correct date/time format to be read by the system?

```
        }
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'adverts_location', $parent->name );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'adverts_person', 'John Doe');
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'adverts_email', 'john@doe.com');
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_expiration_date', '');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a linux timestamp.
To populate your expiration date you can use:

```
strtotime('+20 days');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$convertedDate = DateTime::setTimestamp($post_id);
```

This will convert your timestamp to DateTime, now you can manipulate it as a normal DateTime

```
   $expirationDate = date_add($convertedDate , date_interval_create_from_date_string('20 days'));
```

Or you can try this if you have PHP 5 or greater

```
$convertedDate = date('Y-m-d','1449203160');
$convertedDate = new DateTime($convertedDate);
$convertedDate->add(new DateInterval('P20D'));
echo($convertedDate);
```

Comment: What goes in the update_post_meta() value?  This?  @lucarnosky
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_expiration_date', '$expirationDate');

Comment: Yes, in the expirationData you have the DateTime of the expiration Date

Comment: That doesn't work, it inserts $expirationDate as the data into the field @lucarnosky

Comment: Added another solution. Try this new one

Comment: That will still get written out as echo($convertedDate); in between the '' of the update_post_meta();  How do I get the $convertedDate to write out with the actual data?  @Lucarnosky

Comment: Just take out the echo and put $convertedDate replacing ''